# How to flip the z axis of a Graphics3D in order to create a left-handed coordinate space?

Tags: graphics3d, linear-algebra

I would like to know how this 3D graphic could interpreset the y axis as being the up direction and the z axis flipped so that it creates a left handed coordinate system?

```
Graphics3D[{
    {Red,   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]}, 
    {Green, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}, 
    {Blue,  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}
},
Axes -> True, 
AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

Comment: You should be able to use some `GeometricTransformation` to transform the graphics primitives. Then you can simply reorder the axes labels and you should be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could e.g. negate the z coordinates and exchange y and z. For clarity I write the graphics in a separate statement:

```
gr = {{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]}, {Green, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}, {Blue, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}}  /. {x_?NumericQ, y_, 
    z_} -> {x, -z, y}
Graphics3D[gr, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, z, y}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is mostly what I want, but is there a way for the z axis to be flipped, even if I enter `Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]` for it's arrow instead of `Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}]`?

Comment: ??? But I specified Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]